# Getting cloudfront logs into logstash: ERROR: is not a legal argument to this wrapper, cause it doesn't respond to "read"

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash, amazon-cloudfront, codecs

Logstash version 1.5.0.1

I am trying to use the logstash [s3 input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html) to download cloudfront logs and the [cloudfront codec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-codecs-cloudfront.html) to filter the stream.

I installed the cloudfront codec with `bin/plugin install logstash-codec-cloudfront`.

I am getting the following: **Error: Object: #Version: 1.0 is not a legal argument to this wrapper, cause it doesn't respond to "read".**

Here is the full error message from /var/logs/logstash/logstash.log

```
 {:timestamp=>"2015-08-05T13:35:20.809000-0400", :message=>"A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.\n  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::S3 bucket=>\"[BUCKETNAME]\", prefix=>\"cloudfront/\", region=>\"us-east-1\", type=>\"cloudfront\", secret_access_key=>\"[SECRETKEY]/1\", access_key_id=>\"[KEYID]\", sincedb_path=>\"/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/sincedb\", backup_to_dir=>\"/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/backup\", temporary_directory=>\"/var/lib/logstash/logstash\">\n  Error: Object: #Version: 1.0\n is not a legal argument to this wrapper, cause it doesn't respond to \"read\".", :level=>:error}
```

My logstash config file: /etc/logstash/conf.d/cloudfront.conf

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "[BUCKETNAME]"
    delete => false
    interval => 60 # seconds
    prefix => "cloudfront/"
    region => "us-east-1"
    type => "cloudfront"
    codec => "cloudfront"
    secret_access_key => "[SECRETKEY]"
    access_key_id => "[KEYID]"
    sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/sincedb"
    backup_to_dir => "/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/backup"
    use_ssl => true
  }
}
```

I'm using a similar s3 input stream successfully to get my cloudtrail logs into logstash that is based on the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819970/getting-cloudtrail-logs-into-logstash)  from a stackoverflow post.

CloudFront logfile from s3 (I only included the header from the file):

```
 #Version: 1.0
 #Fields: date time x-edge-location sc-bytes c-ip cs-method cs(Host) cs-uri-stem sc-status cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs-uri-query cs(Cookie) x-edge-result-type x-edge-request-id x-host-header cs-protocol cs-bytes time-taken x-forwarded-for ssl-protocol ssl-cipher x-edge-response-result-type
```

The header looks like it is basically the correct format based on lines 26-29 from the cloudfront plugin github repo [cloudfront_spec.rb](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-cloudfront/blob/master/spec/codecs/cloudfront_spec.rb)
 and the official AWS CloudFront [Access Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) docs.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

[UPDATE 9/9/2015]

Based on this [post](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1550) I tried using the [gzip_lines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-gzip_lines.html) codec plugin, installed with `bin/plugin install logstash-codec-gzip_lines` and parse the file with a filter, unfortunately I am getting the exact same error.  It looks like it is an issue with the first character of the log file having `#`.

For the record, here is the new attempt, including an updated pattern for parsing the cloudfront logfile due to four new fields:

/etc/logstash/conf.d/cloudfront.conf

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "[BUCKETNAME]"
    delete => false
    interval => 60 # seconds
    prefix => "cloudfront/"
    region => "us-east-1"
    type => "cloudfront"
    codec => "gzip_lines"
    secret_access_key => "[SECRETKEY]"
    access_key_id => "[KEYID]"
    sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/sincedb"
    backup_to_dir => "/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/backup"
    use_ssl => true
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
    type => "cloudfront"
    pattern => "%{DATE_EU:date}\t%{TIME:time}\t%{WORD:x_edge_location}\t(?:%{NUMBER:sc_bytes}|-)\t%{IPORHOST:c_ip}\t%{WORD:cs_method}\t%{HOSTNAME:cs_host}\t%{NOTSPACE:cs_uri_stem}\t%{NUMBER:sc_status}\t%{GREEDYDATA:referrer}\t%{GREEDYDATA:User_Agent}\t%{GREEDYDATA:cs_uri_stem}\t%{GREEDYDATA:cookies}\t%{WORD:x_edge_result_type}\t%{NOTSPACE:x_edge_request_id}\t%{HOSTNAME:x_host_header}\t%{URIPROTO:cs_protocol}\t%{INT:cs_bytes}\t%{GREEDYDATA:time_taken}\t%{GREEDYDATA:x_forwarded_for}\t%{GREEDYDATA:ssl_protocol}\t%{GREEDYDATA:ssl_cipher}\t%{GREEDYDATA:x_edge_response_result_type}"
  }

mutate {
    type => "cloudfront"
        add_field => [ "listener_timestamp", "%{date} %{time}" ]
    }

date {
      type => "cloudfront"
      match => [ "listener_timestamp", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, changing from

```
    codec > "gzip_lines"
```

to

```
    codec => "plain"
```

in the input fixed it for me. Looks like S3 input automatically uncompress gzip files. https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-s3/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb#L13

Answer (score 1):

This is reported as bug here https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-cloudfront/issues/2

Not fixed since 2016

Answer (score 0):

FTR here is the full config that is working for me:

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "[BUCKET NAME]"
    delete => false
    interval => 60 # seconds
    prefix => "CloudFront/"
    region => "us-east-1"
    type => "cloudfront"
    codec => "plain"
    secret_access_key => "[SECRETKEY]"
    access_key_id => "[KEYID]"
    sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/sincedb"
    backup_to_dir => "/opt/logstash_input/s3/cloudfront/backup"
    use_ssl => true
  }
}

filter {
        if [type] == "cloudfront" {
                if ( ("#Version: 1.0" in [message]) or ("#Fields: date" in [message])) {
                        drop {}
                }

                grok {
                        match => { "message" => "%{DATE_EU:date}\t%{TIME:time}\t%{WORD:x_edge_location}\t(?:%{NUMBER:sc_bytes}|-)\t%{IPORHOST:c_ip}\t%{WORD:cs_method}\t%{HOSTNAME:cs_host}\t%{NOTSPACE:cs_uri_stem}\t%{NUMBER:sc_status}\t%{GREEDYDATA:referrer}\t%{GREEDYDATA:User_Agent}\t%{GREEDYDATA:cs_uri_stem}\t%{GREEDYDATA:cookies}\t%{WORD:x_edge_result_type}\t%{NOTSPACE:x_edge_request_id}\t%{HOSTNAME:x_host_header}\t%{URIPROTO:cs_protocol}\t%{INT:cs_bytes}\t%{GREEDYDATA:time_taken}\t%{GREEDYDATA:x_forwarded_for}\t%{GREEDYDATA:ssl_protocol}\t%{GREEDYDATA:ssl_cipher}\t%{GREEDYDATA:x_edge_response_result_type}" }
                }

                mutate {
                        add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
                        add_field => [ "listener_timestamp", "%{date} %{time}" ]
                }

                date {
                        match => [ "listener_timestamp", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                }

                date {
                        locale => "en"
                        timezone => "UCT"
                        match => [ "listener_timestamp", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                        target => "@timestamp"
                        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
                }
        }
}
```